# Vue.Js(2) : Property or method "hideModel" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have just started to learn VueJs and trying to bind a `clickEvent` and hide the message `<article>`. But it show the following warning-

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "hideModel" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Although when i m trying  in-line like.

```
<button type='button' v-on:click='isInvisible=false'>X</button>
```

It working fine. But with the function it not working.

**index.html**

```
<div id="root">
 <message title="my-message" body="lorem ipsum sit ben"></message>
 <message title="Other message" body="This is other message"> 
  </message>
 </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.css" />
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
Vue.component('message', {
props:['title', 'body'],

data(){
    return {
        isVisible:true
    };
},
template:`<article class="message" v-show='isVisible'>
            <div class="message-header">
            <p>{{ title }}</p>
            <button type='button' v-on:click='hideModel'>X</button>
            </div>
            <div class="message-body">
                {{body}}
            </div>
        </article>`,
method:{
hideModel(){
  this.isVisible=false;
}
}

})


new Vue({
el:"#root",
});
```

Comment: It's `methods`, not `method`, since there can be multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of mistyping. All methods should be placed into the `methods`. Don't forget about `s` in the end.

```
...
methods:{
  hideModel(){
    this.isVisible=false;
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

rename method to methods and you should be fine. You can add any arbitrary number of keys to the Vue component constructor object, but they will only be picked up by Vue if they correspond to the the known properties. Hence 'method' will be ignored, whereas 'methods' will work.